# JQuery Mobile executing multiple times a delegate

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile to create a website with multiple pages in different html files. In one file I have this DIV:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page3" style="overflow-x: hidden !important;">
 <div data-role="content">...
 </div>
</div>
```

I have defined in the header of the first page a delegate as:

```
$(document).delegate('[id="page3"]', 'pageshow', function () {
    alert('page3');
};
```

The problem is that this delegate is fired once the first time the page is loaded, twice the second time, etc... each time you visit the page the delegate is fired one time more.

The process is this:

> Visit the page1 -> page 3 (one alert) -> page 1 -> page 3 (two alerts) ....

I've tried to check if there is more than one element with that id executing `$('#page3')` on the firebug console and I get only one item.

I'm not sure what else I can check to debug the problem.

**EDIT:**

page1.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/delegation.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript">
           delegation.delegate3()
        </script>  
    </head>
    <body> ....
```

page3.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/delegation.js"></script>     
    </head>
    <body> 
       <div data-role="page" id="page3" style="overflow-x: hidden !important;">
          <div data-role="content">...
           </div>
       </div>....
```

delegation.js

```
var delegation = (function () {
  return {
     delegate3:function delegate3() {
    $(document).delegate('[id="page3"]', 'pageshow', function () {
           alert('page3');
         };
   }
 })();
```

Comment: Can you include the block where you are writing this event

Comment: I've included part of the code that interacts with that delegate, If you think the problem is in other part of the code I can include more code. Thanks!

Comment: Delegated event handlers should be run outside of the `data-role="page"` elements. If you place the code within a `data-role="page"` element then it will be executed every time that page is added to the DOM (i.e. every time it displays).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pages are rebuild each time, so it will find another page and execute the event on the new and the old page.

Try this:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#page3", function () {
    alert('page3');
};
```

or replace `on` with `one` to execute once;

Comment: `one` fixed the problem, `on` was having the same problem as `delegate`. Thanks!